# File get contents vs Path Info

Tags: php

i'm trying to get a path from $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and use it in file_get_contents function but i'm having some issues:

assuming i have the following link :

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/http://www.example.com
```

using path info i get the the last url: /http://www.example.com and delete the first character put it into a variable and then use it in file_get_contents as follows:

```
$link = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],1,strlen($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']));
$linkcontents = file_get_contents($link);
```

but this doesn't work! i don't know what's wrong knowing that it works when i put a file.extension instead of an url?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http:/www.google.com): failed to open stream: Invalid argument. I guess it should be file_get_contents("http:/www.google.com")!!!

Comment: That is not a valid link.

Comment: that `http:/` isn't `http://`

Comment: even if there is no http:// it doesn't work!

Comment: Isn't there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to that question is removing the http:// from the link and putting it in file_get_contents like this:

url: http://www.example.com/index.php/www.example.com

```
$linkcontents = file_get_contents("https://".substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],1));
```

This will output the link correctly